# Swagger Code Gen - package javax.annotation does not exist

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

Why is swagger-codegen generating project with missing dependencies?

Running:
`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l java -i swagger.json`

Generates a project with this for example:

```java
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2021-04-27T18:37:06.211+08:00")
public class Table {
  @SerializedName("requiredIndexColumns")
  private List<Column> requiredIndexColumns = null;
```

Where `javax.annotation.Generate` cannot be resolved.
And then compiling the generated project throws: `Error:(33,18) java: package javax.annotation does not exist`

Here's how to test this (using a public swagger):

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.19/swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.19.jar -O swagger-codegen-cli.jar
```

Then run:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l java -i https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -o petstore
```

Comment: What is your Java version? [javax.annotation.Generated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/annotation/Generated.html) seems to exists in Java 10, but no longer in Java 11. I expect you'll need to add either [JSR 250 Common Annotations For The JavaTM Platform](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/jsr250-api) or [Javax Annotation API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api)

Answer (score 13):

Formalizing the comment left by [Scratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte), if you are using jdk11, you need to add the [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api) explicitly in your dependency management tool

For example in maven

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax-annotation-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to run with this command:

`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l java -i https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -o petstore -DhideGenerationTimestamp=true`

The option to turn off @javax.annotation.Generated date in Java Classes

Comment: @Edd There is no version 6.2.0. Current version is 3.0.54, see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases